# hide custom search bar on start

Tags: ios, swift, searchbar

in my swift 2 app i have a table view controller
where i added a custom search bar (dark grey row)

in the viewDidLoad i call

```
configureCustomSearchController()
```

this is the function:

```
  func configureCustomSearchController() {
       customSearchController = CustomSearchController(
          searchResultsController: self,
          searchBarFrame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, MyTable.frame.size.width, 50.0),
          MyTable.tableHeaderView = customSearchController.customSearchBar
          customSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
          customSearchController.customDelegate = self
        }



    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }

    func didStartSearching() {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }


    func didTapOnSearchButton() {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }


    func didTapOnCancelButton() {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }

    func didChangeSearchText(searchText: String) {
        // DO SOMETHING
    }
```

[image]

My Question is, how can i hide the searcher, if my tableview will appear and show the sidebar if i pull down.

a pull down refresh function is available.

Comment: so you want to display the searchbar only when user pull down refresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found my solution:

**viewDidLoad**

```
MYTable.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: -1, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

this hide the searchbar on start and if i scroll a little bit up, the search Bar will be visible

Comment: Finally someone found an easy solution!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show searchbar when user scroll down then add this Code

```
  self.MyTable.tableHeaderView = customSearchController
        self.MyTable.contentOffset  = CGPointMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(customSearchController.frame))
        customSearchController.delegate = self
```

Comment: i try the contentOffset - but my tableview will looks every time the same position .

Comment: can you please post a screenshot of your table View and storyBoard

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the header which contains your custom search bar you can try the following solutions:

When you have to hide header (At start):

```
tableview.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,44)
```

When you have to show header (On the pull down action ):

`tableview.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,0)` 
Ref:https://stackoverflow.com/a/14433304/4557505

Another option is

```
table.tableHeaderView = nil
```

And later if you want to show it then just assign it again,

```
table.tableHeaderView = theHeaderView;
```

You can find more information about this on https://stackoverflow.com/a/8079933/4557505

Hope this may help you

Else you may set your search bar on the viewController's view and show/hide that based on your pull to refresh